# Boolean value defined after evaluating the conditions declared in an 'array'

Tags: swift, boolean

### **Can a boolean value be defined if I use an 'array' of conditions?**

*(This is something that I imagined but I'm not completely sure if it is possible or correct... I'm a beginner in swift)*

**In short:** I want the variable 'alpha' to be true or false after evaluating an array of simple conditions. I know I can use an 'if' or 'switch' to achieve this, but I want to know if there is a more simple way to do it. (I was inspired by the fact I can declare an 'if' with several conditions seppared by commas)

**Case 1:**

```
var red = 2
var green = 3
var blue = 4

var alpha = red > 1; green > 2; blue > 3
// Can this be done?

// result: alpha is true
```

**Case 2:**

```
var red = 0
var green = 4
var blue = 2

var alpha = red > 1; green > 2; blue > 3

// result: alpha is false
```

Under this logic, alpha is 'true' if EVERY condition is 'true', otherwise, alpha is 'false'

---

**What have I done so far?:**

I tried to test this in the playground but it always print 'true' for alpha.

---

*Suggestions to achieve what I want in other ways are welcome*

Thank you :)

Comment: `var alpha = red > 1 && green > 2 && blue > 3`

Comment: Thank you @vacawama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options

1. As suggested by vacawana with the AND (`&&`) operator

   ```
   let alpha = red > 1 && green > 2 && blue > 3
   ```
2. With an `if` expression evaluating multiple conditions **comma** separated

   ```
   var alpha = false
   if red > 1, green > 2, blue > 3 { alpha = true }
   ```

Comment: (For `2'` :) ). Possibly worth mentioning that `alpha` can still be kept immutable also for the 2nd alternative; `let` declaration followed by conditional branches all leading to its instantiation (`if .. { } else { }`). E.g. `let alpha: Bool; if red > 1, green > 2, blue > 3 { alpha = true } else { alpha = false }`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a semicolon `;` separates the statements from each other and does *not* evaluate them as a single statement.

What you have written:

```
var alpha = red > 1; 
green > 2; 
blue > 3
```

So it only checks if `red > 0` and ignores the other color values.
The other conditions are evaluated, but assigned to nothing.

In order to evaluate all the conditions, you have to chain them with a logical AND.

```
var alpha = red > 1 && green > 2 && blue > 3
```